# Proper way of updating a system in an ECS

Tags: c++, entity

I am currently trying to implement an (sort-of) Entity-Component-System.
I've got the gist of it, that is, how an ECS is supposed to work. So far i have 4 classes in my design (not yet fully implemented): `EntityWorld` is a global container for systems, entities and their respective components. It is responsible for updating systems/stepping. `EntitySystem` represents the base class for a system, with a virtual `update`-function. `Entity` is a container, basically with a list of components and an id, nothing more. `EntityComponent` represents a component. Now, i thought about making it possible to multithread my systems, but i think i've ran into a problem here. Suppose my `EntityWorld` stores its entities in the simplest way possible, in a `std::vector<Entity*>` for example. Now, that list would either be fully passed to a system when it is updated, or the `EntityWorld` loops through this list and sends the entities to the systems one-by-one. In my understanding though, when using multiple threads, this would require me to lock the whole list every time a system is being updated. That would practically equal zero increase in performance, since the other threads are always waiting for the list to get free. Is there a better way to implement this? So multiple threads can be updated (and r/w to entites at the same time)?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When going with ECS, it's almost always beneficial to go with DOD (Data Oriented Design) as well. It means that `Component`s are held in a sort of `ComponentManager` classes or so, while `Entities` contain only (shared) pointers to the actual components. Multi-threading is usually achieved by running each system with its corresponding `ComponentManager` in different thread (although, if multiple systems operate on the same `Component`, or you need to sync some `Component`s, it might become a problem)